# Java Class Collect All Child Attributes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I want to create a class that may have its children attributes. For example:

```
public class Parent {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

```
public class ChildA extends Parent {
    private String c;
    private String d;
}
```

```
public class ChildB extends Parent {
    private String e;
    private String f;
}
```

How could `Parent` have attributes of `ChildA` when `ChildA` is passed and `ChildB` when `ChildB` is passed? It may be done by get it as a plain `Object`, however how to do it in more OOP way?

Comment: If you give context maybe this can be done a better way and answered under the `design-patterns` tag.  This is usually a sign of incomplete design.

Comment: what do you mean `class that may have its children attributes`?

Comment: What does it mean? _`ChildA` is passed_

Comment: HI @alcantula, from what I understand, when object is of type ChildA, it should have access to a,b,c,d and when of type ChildB, it should have access to a,b,e,f. If that is the requirement, then you can make member variables of Parent `protected` and they will be available inside its children directly. Not sure this is what you wanted, if not let me know and I will try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it ... assuming that I am correctly understanding what you are asking:

```
public class Parent {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public List<String> collect() {
        return Arrays.asList(a, b);
    }
}

public class ChildA extends Parent {
    private String c;
    private String d;

    @Override
    public List<String> collect() {
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.addAll(super.collect());
        res.add(c);
        res.add(d);
        return res;
    }
}
```

The parent class has a straight-forward implementation for `collect()`.

The child class overrides the `collect()` implementation from its parent, and in the method it calls the parent classes `collect()`.

This approach gives rather repetitious code.

---

An alternative approach would be to use reflection to find all of the fields, break open the `private` access, and retrieve and add all of their values to a `List` object.  The code to do that is non-trivial, but it only needs to be implemented once.

The reflection approach is breaking type abstraction to access private fields in another class.  That is is a bit anti-OO ... depending on your point of view.